# google-chrome constantly time out inside docker container even with "--disable-dev-shm-usage" hosted on fly.io

Tags: linux, docker, google-chrome, rust, shared-memory

I am using [chromiumoxide](https://github.com/mattsse/chromiumoxide) crate in rust to automate headless chrome inside docker container.

Here is the browser configuration:

```
let config = BrowserConfig::builder()
    .chrome_executable(chrome_bin)
    .no_sandbox()
    .disable_cache()
    .args(vec![
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--shm-size=2g",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    ])
    .enable_request_intercept()
    .build()?;

// create a `Browser` that spawns a `chromium` process running with UI (`with_head()`, headless is default)
// and the handler that drives the websocket etc.
let (browser, mut handler) = Browser::launch(config).await?;
```

After deploying this to a docker container hosted on a vm in fly.io (shared-cpu-x4 and 4GB memory), it gives error after visiting a few urls:

```
[error]could not make HTTP request to instance: connection error: timed out
[info] WARN Reaped child process with pid: 480 and signal: SIGPIPE, core dumped? false
```

Command `df -h /dev/shm` inside docker container running on cloud server produces:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
shm             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Command `df -h` inside docker container running on cloud server produces:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
/dev/vda        7.8G  1.1G  6.3G  15% /
shm             2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

My question is what is causing chrome to time out every single time after running it for only 1 minute or so? I have googled everywhere but could not pinpoint the issue here.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
# Will build and cache the binary and dependent crates in release mode
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo,from=rust:latest,source=/usr/local/cargo \
    --mount=type=cache,target=target \
    cargo build --release && mv ./target/release/api ./api

# Runtime image
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

# Fetch chrome
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
  wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Run as "app" user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash app

USER app
WORKDIR /app

# Get compiled binaries from builder's cargo install directory
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/api /app/api

# Run the app
CMD ./api
```